# Can't figure out how to map separate points

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, gis

I'm new to d3 and was hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to map a set of coordinates as points onto a map.

I used Mike Bostock's airports voronoi map as a starting point, and so far I've got the base map working. I can even overlay the points I want like he did with airports based on coordinates in a `.tsv`:

[image]
Unfortunately, the blue dots are plotted as a single element and I'd like to create individual paths or circles for each point. This is my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/cerealcommas/ofmz52uu/3/

I also have the data in following JSON format, but to be honest, JSON syntax completely befuddles me, so I'm not sure how to manipulate it correctly.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [27.47197, -80.32435]
    },
    "properties": {}
},

        ...

 {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [26.25161, -81.82374]
    },
    "properties": {}
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of type Point instead of MultiPoints iterate through the points and make path:

Referring your fiddle your present code

```
//add points
svg.append("path")
    .datum({
    type: "MultiPoint",
    coordinates: lionfish
})
    .attr("class", "points")
    .attr("d", path);
```

Doing it with type Point

```
//add points
    lionfish.forEach(function(d){
        svg.append("path")
        .datum({
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: d
        })
        .attr("class", "points")
        .attr("d", path);
    });
```